# Question about the malloc function on c programming

Tags: c

why the following *t value is 0?

```
float *t = 1 + (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * sizeof(float));
printf("add part: %f\n", (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * sizeof(float)));
printf("*t %f\n", *t);
```

Terminal Output:
step 1
add part: 0.000000
*t 0.000000

Comment: Could you explain, in your own words, what you think your program is doing?

Comment: copy form my text book example. not my program.

Comment: Cite the textbook so we can all avoid it! The allocation size  makes no sense semantically, and you cannot free the allocation through `t`.  The first `printf` interprets a `float*` as a `float` and is a clear memory leak - was that perhaps a `scanf` in the original text (though that would still make little sense).  The second `printf` interprets initialised memory as a `float`; it could print anything. If this is truly from your text book (which I doubt), then presumably it explains the code (otherwise it is not a text book worth the name). What explanation does it give?

Comment: The full example as below: #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    float *t = 1 + (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * sizeof(float));

    t--;

    *t = 8.0;
    t[1] = *t / 4.0;
    t++;
    t[-1] = *t / 2.0;

    printf("%f\n", *t);
    free(--t);
    return 0;
} the output is 2.0 and I cannot really understand why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is very confusing and the output is undefined for both `printf` calls:

- allocating `sizeof(float) * sizeof(float)` is disturbing: what is the purpose?
- adding `1` to the return value of `malloc()` computes a pointer to the second `float` in the allocated array (assuming `sizeof(float) > 1`.
- `printf("add part: %f\n", ...)` expects a `double` or a `float`value that will be converted to `double`, `(float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * sizeof(float))` is a pointer to `float`, incompatible with the expected argument type, the behavior is undefined.
- `printf("*t %f\n", *t);` outputs the value of the second element of the array allocated via `malloc()`. This array is uninitialized so the behavior is undefined.

The output can be `0.000000` or some other value or a crash if the array happens to contain trap values such as signalling NaNs. You are lucky to see anything at all, `0.000000` probably comes from the allocated object having zero bits in the second element, but you cannot rely on this, it is just a coincidence.